# Need assistance regarding CLLocationManager Heading

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
```

I want to access heading which this method's `manager.heading.trueHeading` is providing.

But mostly I found this

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

for heading updates.

Are both solutions ok to use?

and how can I convert heading to string for sending to web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want and when you want it, both solutions seems ok but `didUpdateLocations` will be called only if the location has changed, and `didUpdateHeading` will be called only when the heading has changed.

If the heading changes but not the location, only `didUpdateHeading` will be called, and viceversa.

Comment: Thanks for reply, please also tell how to convert heading to string from sending it on web service.

Comment: Well, that highly depends on how your webservice needs the string, you can create a new question asking specifically that.